# In liferay how to change permission of DL folder programatically

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want to change permission of created DL folder in liferay through java class: let us consider foldername id "temp"

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the folder 'temp':

```
Folder tempFolder = dlAppLocalService.getFolder(groupId, parentFolderId, "temp");
```

and you have to set the permisssions for the 'tempFolder' resource.

For instance, if you want to set VIEW permission to GUEST role:

```
Role guestRole = roleLocalService.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.GUEST);

resourcePermissionLocalService.setResourcePermissions(companyId, DLFolder.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL, String.valueOf(tempFolder.getFolderId()), guestRole.getRoleId(), new String[]{"VIEW"});
```

You can see the complete API here

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.html

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil** service to give permission to your DlFolder as below :

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(companyId,DLFolder.
class.getName(),ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,""+
folder.getFolderId(), roleId, permissions);
```

Fins details on it from [here](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/java/liferay/liferay-script-setting-document-library-folder-permissions/)!